# MySQL RegExp with cyrillic

Tags: mysql, regex, cyrillic

I have simple MySql-query:

> mysql> SELECT 'Я' RegExp '[аб]';
>
> -> 1

Unexpectedly! But result says it's true.
The answer is the same for almost all Cyrillic characters.

Why MySQL gives false answer?
How can I get the right answer?

---

*P.S.:*
***RegExp '(а|б)'***
*is true. But, unfortunately, it is less productive.*

Comment: About the only way to test Cyrillic in a regexp, is to play with HEX.